# How to find curvature when the first derivative of the parametrization is not regular

Tags: multivariable-calculus, curvature, parametrization

I'm having trouble coming up with a solution on the  following question:

**Find a formula for the curvature of the cycloid given by** $$ x = t−\sin (t)\ ,\ y = 1−\cos(t)$$.

I have the following:

$$r(t)=<t-\sin(t),1-\cos(t)>$$
$$r'(t)= <1-\cos(t), \sin(t)>$$

I'm stuck here because $r'(t)= 0$ when $t=0$, which means the derivative of $r(t) $is not regular. That means I can't use the regular formula for curvature, $$ \dfrac{||\det (r'(t) , r''(t))||}{  ||r'(t)||^3} $$

I'm not sure where to go from here and any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi ! You shall use Latex , its more pleasant to read !

Comment: What is X  ? You mean $\det$ ?

Comment: Note that there isn"t $z$ component

Answer (score 0):

The cusp is a special point of the cycloid. Try to find the limits of the curvature when $t\to0+$ and $t\to 0-$.

Answer (score 0):

You have :

$$ \kappa=\dfrac{\cos(t)-1}{(\sqrt{2(1-\cos(t))})^3} = \dfrac{\cos(t)-1}{\sqrt{64\sin(\frac{t}{2})^6}}  \sim\dfrac{1}{2^{\frac{3}{2}}t} $$

So divergent.